# Spring exception Handling : the @exception handler is not invoked

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Im' working on a spring application lately using hibernate, thymeleaf and spring security.

I stumbled upon a situation : i made a custom Exception :

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public class GlobalUrlParametersErrorsException extends RuntimeException {

    private String errorMsgSignature;

    private String errorMsgContent;

    private String redirectionUrl;

    public String getErrorMsgSignature() {
        return errorMsgSignature;
    }

    public void setErrorMsgSignature(String errorMsgSignature) {
        this.errorMsgSignature = errorMsgSignature;
    }

    public String getErrorMsgContent() {
        return errorMsgContent;
    }

    public void setErrorMsgContent(String errorMsgContent) {
        this.errorMsgContent = errorMsgContent;
    }

    public String getRedirectionUrl() {
        return redirectionUrl;
    }

    public void setRedirectionUrl(String redirectionUrl) {
        this.redirectionUrl = redirectionUrl;
    }

    public GlobalUrlParametersErrorsException(String errorMsgSignature, String errorMsgContent, String redirectionUrl){

        this.errorMsgSignature = errorMsgSignature;
        this.errorMsgContent = errorMsgContent;
        this.redirectionUrl = redirectionUrl;
    }

}
```

This exception is extended by some other custom exceptions i wrote.

To handle these exceptions i added a `@ControllerAdvice` :

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalDefaultExceptionHandler {
//some other exception like hibernate exception ...

    @ExceptionHandler( value = GlobalUrlParametersErrorsException.class)//{InvalidDateException.class, InvalidRole.class, NoSuchUser.class, NoSuchNotification.class,NoSuchConsultation.class,NoSuchRdv.class})
    public ModelAndView whenUrlDateParametersSuckMethod(RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,GlobalUrlParametersErrorsException e){

        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute(e.getErrorMsgSignature(),e.getErrorMsgContent());
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:"+e.getRedirectionUrl());
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
    public ModelAndView defaultErrorHandler(HttpServletRequest req, Exception e) throws Exception {
        ModelAndView m = new ModelAndView("errors/defaultError");
        m.addObject("exception", e.toString());
        m.addObject("url", req.getRequestURL());
        return m;
    }

}
```

But still my exceptions that i throw in the controller are not caught (i get glassfish error page)

So what's wrong with with my approch ?

PS: When i remove the exception handler of the my custom exception, and only let the other one , it works

Comment: have a look [here](http://ankursinghal86.blogspot.in/2014/07/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc.html)

Comment: this article is taken from [here](http://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc) and yet i read ,i still don't get why mine is not working

Comment: Unsure of that, but I have never seen in Spring documentation what was the priority when more than one `@ExceptionHandler` *in same class* matches the Exception. That would be coherent with the fact that if you have only one exception handler, it works. Don't you have any message in the logs ?

Comment: The purpuse of `@ControllerAdvice` is to let you handel all of your exceptions, which are commun in all of your controllers, in one class (so that you don't have to write the same code in all controllers), so it's pretty logical to put them all in the same class (ps : see the documentation i put in the comment above), and concerning the priority of exceptions, i tried using this class without the last `@ExceptionHandler` (handling Exception.Class), and it still didn't work :/

Comment: I agree with suggestion provided by @Aissasa. Please go through references mentioned in this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52392820/is-it-good-practice-to-have-generic-exception-class-handler-in-global-exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you can't use RedirectAttributes in the method arguments of an @ExceptionHandler: the handler gets ignored.
Currently [the docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-exceptionhandler) say:

> Much like standard controller methods annotated with a @RequestMapping annotation, the method arguments and return values of @ExceptionHandler methods can be flexible. For example, the HttpServletRequest can be accessed in Servlet environments and the PortletRequest in Portlet environments.

It looks like you could use the same parameters of a @RequestMapping method, but it doesn't work with RedirectAttributes.

A workaround is to forward to a @RequestMapping:

```
@ExceptionHandler(MyException.class)
public String handleMyException(MyException e) {
    return "forward:/internalError";
}

@RequestMapping("/internalError")
public String internalError(RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    // do stuff with redirectAttributes...
    return "redirect:/someplace";   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to add this line in your spring configuration:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

If you don't put it, your class won't be loaded.

Comment: it's been some time since i worked on this project, but i used java config and not xml, and i think i added its equivalent in java config :)