# Is it good practice to have Generic Exception class handler in global exception handler with spring rest?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception

I was referring few articles to create global exception handler using `@ControllerAdvice` for my rest api project using spring. The purpose of this is to send proper formatted response to the client in the case of exception occurred. In some articles they have added `Throwable` or `Exception` in global exception handler.
Should I replace it with `RunTimeException` as this block is for exception occurred  at runtime?

**Exception Handler code:**

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler{

    @ExceptionHandler(NoDataFoundException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(code=HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handle(NoDataFoundException ex){
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse(ex.getMessage(), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value());
        ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> response = new ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse>(errorResponse, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        return response;
    }
    ..... more methods to handle custom exceptions

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    @ResponseStatus(code=HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handle(Exception ex){
        ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse("Something went wrong", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
        ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> response = new ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse>(errorResponse, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        return response;
    }
}
```

**ErrorResponse code:**

```
public class ErrorResponse {

    private String message;
    private int statusCode;

    public ErrorResponse(String message, int statusCode) {
        super();
        this.message = message;
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
    }
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
    public int getStatusCode() {
        return statusCode;
    }
    public void setStatusCode(int statusCode) {
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
    }
}
```

**References:**

1. https://dzone.com/articles/exception-handling-in-spring-boot-rest-web-service
2. https://github.com/in28minutes/spring-boot-examples/tree/master/spring-boot-2-rest-service-exception-handling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I replace it with RunTimeException as this block is for
>   exception occurred at runtime?

To make sure that you catch any exception thrown and never handled by your components or any exception handler with a more typed exception than `Exception`, you should have a handler for `Exception`.
A handler for `RuntimeException` is not enough because checked exception are also thrown at runtime and if the method declarations of your high level components specify `throws Exception` or `throws "any checked exception"`, a checked exception could be propagated until the client or here the container that will apply a default behavior.
For example imagine this rest controller method declaration that could be make this situation to happen :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Foo> getOne(@PathVariable long id) throws Exception {
       // ....           
}
```

And to override this default Spring behavior, you will want to add a handler for `Exception`.
Of course it doesn't mean that declaring a handler only for `Exception` is the way but you may have some exception with no specific handling and for that a generic handling is fine.

Comment: I would not have this scenario where controller throws some exception. I handled checked exceptions at service layer and thrown some un-checked exception.

Comment: It is a good thing but do you think that you have this design guaranteed for the whole life of the application ? Not sure.

Comment: Other example. Suppose that your application (itself or a library) uses reflection to instantiate objects by using `Class.newInstance()` that may throw checked exceptions without declaring it. The exception will be probably not caught by using a `RuntimeException` handler. In a general way, think to making your app robust now, for unpredictable cases and for the future.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, having an exception handler handle `Exception` seems a bit lazy to me.  Since `Exception` is checked, you should be responsible for handling or recovering from the error.  If you're *not* able to recover from the error, or the circumstance you're in prevents you from writing code that allows you to elegantly recover, it should be re-thrown in a `RuntimeException` instead to indicate the issue.

Of course, exception handlers serve two purposes:

- They give you the power to define a standard of how error responses look and what they contain in detail.
- They give you the ability to log the error so you can go back later and fix it.

I'd strongly encourage the pattern of re-throwing checked `Exception`s as unchecked, and handling those in exception handlers.  As a fail-safe catch-all, you can use a generic exception handler for `Exception` to catch all of the spots that weren't converted over, and to log what happened.

It should *never* be the case that you as a developer allow an `Exception` to propagate all the way to the top without explicit reason.